# Ideas/Advice for my Roof Rebuild

Tags: roof

I need some advice about drawing up blueprints for a new roof on our house. Thanks to some shoddy workmanship on an addition before we bought the house we need to completely remove the existing roof (framing and all) and put a new solid roof over the whole house. I am trying to decide what kind of framing structure to use on the new roof. We are also doing a complete floor plan remodel on the interior of the house. I have attached the blueprint of the final product.

The dimensions of the house are what is making this somewhat difficult. The house if 42x50, so that would make for a larger than usual truss. We are also wanting to have an attic space that we can finish someday to add a couple of rooms and have vaulted ceilings in part of the house.

From the research that I have done, it seems like the simplest and best solution is to use a structural ridge beam to help support the new roof. This would allow us to leave the entire attic space open and would also simplify the construction process because we should be able to leave the ceilings up in the house until we are ready to redo them as well. It also adds strength to the house because half of the weight of the roof would be supported by the ridge beam instead of all of the weight resting on the exterior walls.

I have attached an outline of where the ridge beam would go as well as where the vaulted ceilings would be. Can anyone offer any advise or a better alternative to a ridge beam?

**House Blueprint:**
[image: a]
<sub>(source: [bateswebdesign.com](http://www.bateswebdesign.com/random/render1.jpg))</sub>

**Ridge Beam Blueprint:**
[image: a]
<sub>(source: [bateswebdesign.com](http://www.bateswebdesign.com/random/ridge_beam_outline.jpg))</sub>

**Current Roof:**
[image: a]
<sub>(source: [bateswebdesign.com](http://www.bateswebdesign.com/random/roof_outline.jpg))</sub>

Comment: How was the roof laid out before? What sort of slope are you after? A 22° slope is going to give you a roughly 17' high vaulted ceiling, but isn't going to leave a lot of attic space.

Comment: I have just added a diagram of the existing roof. We are thinking about a 7/12 pitch (about 30° slope) which would put the peak at about 20'

Answer (score 1):

Call an architect. Seriously call one. Let them know what you'd like to do. Ask for some ideas. They can take the structure, age, other home styles in the area and give you a slew of options that are suitable and sound.

And it shouldn't cost that must either. They can suggest and sketch out rather quickly the style based on many factors including load weight, pitch, roof material you're going to use and more. There's modern materials, ways to get light in, sun roofs, venting, insulation that all factor in to a design.

A local architect is also in the know on building codes etc.

Looking around for ideas it's one thing but if you're serious about replacing the roof, an architect is the one to consult.

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Home Improvement. Thanks for the answer; keep 'em coming. And, you should probably [take our tour](//diy.stackexchange.com/tour) so you'll know how best to contribute here.